# Create a time Offset from string with NodaTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nodatime

I have a string that represents the offset of a particular customer. An example is `UTC+1:00`. It is always the offset relative to UTC, so the string will always start with `UTC` followed by `+` or `-` and then the offset in format `hh:mm`.

The question is, how can I take this string and convert it into an offset? I do not want a date and time object with an offset applied, I just want an object that symbolizes my offset, something I can then later apply to a date, which is something different altogether.

At the title says, I'm looking to use NodaTime for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var pattern = OffsetPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("'UTC'+H:mm");
var offset = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far Jon, but it looks like this isn't fully solved yet. It looks like at least one string appears in the following format: `UTC±00:00`, which is breaking the pattern... So it looks like following UTC can be a `+`, a `-` or a `±`. How can I make the pattern work for all the combinations above?

Comment: @JohnUbuntu: I would probably just special case `UTC±00:00` as an exact match first. That symbol would only be valid if the offset is 0.